# How to accept only one of multiple fields in Go Validator?

Tags: validation, go

```
type CoolName struct {
    Foo string  `json:"foo"`
    Bar string  `json:"bar"`
}
```

With the Go validator, I want to make only one of these two fields required and give an error **if the content of both fields is full**.

I used `required_without` but it only helps with requiring one of them. I can't figure out how can i validate if both fields doesn't have a content at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just spent some time fighting this same issue, but I seem to have figured it out:

```golang
type CoolName struct {
    Foo string  `json:"foo" validate:"required_without=Bar,excluded_with=Bar"`
    Bar string  `json:"bar" validate:"required_without=Foo,excluded_with=Foo"`
}
```

This does the trick and even makes some sence. However, I find the documentation on `_with`/`_without` tags a little misleading:

> The field under validation must be present and not empty only when any of the other specified fields are not present.

For me this implies that "field must be present <=> (if and only if) other field is not".

Answer (score 1):

i have follow this and work for me,
ref : https://github.com/go-playground/validator/issues/617

```
type Auth struct { 
APIKey   string `json:"apiKey" validate:"required_without=Username,required_without=Password"`
Username string `json:"username" validate:"required_without=APIKey"`
Password string `json:"password" validate:"required_without=APIKey"`}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But what i am trying to do is as such:
foo: "content", bar: "" => accepted ; foo: "content", bar: "another" => error.
I hope i am clear enough.